# Narrow down Union type of argument inside function

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a function that accepts an argument which can be either of type A or B.  In case A is passed, it is converted to B for further processing internally.

To keep it simple, consider the following example using int/float to illustrate the scenario:

```
import typing


def foo(x: typing.Union[int, float]):
    if type(x) is int:
        x = float(x)

    x.as_integer_ratio()  # method of float that does not exist for int
```

The last line results in a mypy error:

> error: Item "int" of "Union[int, float]" has no attribute "as_integer_ratio"

Is there a nice way to make it clear to mypy that after the `if` the type of `x` basically changed from the Union to always being float without adding an additional variable?

Comment: try to set the type in the assignment: `x: float = float(x)`. Maybe after mypy parses it it realizes it's a bloat by then.

Comment: @samthegolden It doesn't seem to be possible to change the type this way.  It results in a "Name 'x' already defined" error.

Comment: You're right, I forgot that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `if` statement to:

```
if isinstance(x, int):
```

This line is better handled by mypy, now after executing `if` and `x = float(x)` it understands that x cannot be int  and the error is gone.